# RDP with Mac and Server Essentials

Tags: windows, mac, rdp

Using Windows Server Essentials 2011, can a Mac connect through the remote web portal and (possibly using a third-party tool, if necessary), create a remote desktop connection to their work machine?  Any help you can provide in this instance would be awesome.

UPDATE:  let me be very clear.  I am not looking to use RDP on a mac to control a windows machine... I understand how to do that.  What I AM looking to do is know if there is a tool in place to allow an RWA (remote web access) TO a Mac over Windows Server Essentials.

Comment: This has been answered at http://serverfault.com/questions/56650/ts-gateway-support-for-mac

Answer (score 1):

Let me save you some headaches... from trying to re-invent the wheel.  I believe that includes the necessary plugins for accessing RDP through HTTPS.

http://www.microsoft.com/mac/remote-desktop-client

Comment: The current MAC remote desktop client version **does** support the Remote Desktop Gateway protocol functionality (RDP over HTTPS mainly). I am not sure if it will work through the Remote Web Workplace portal though - it either starts Remote Desktop through ActiveX which won't work in OS X / Safari or allows you to download an .rdp config file, which, AFAICS, is not read by the Mac Remote Desktop Client version, so you would have to resort to creating a custom RDP client config by yourself.  What I also do not know is if SBS Essentials actually has the RD Gateway feature.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft makes an RDP client for OSX, there is also an open source project named `cord` that will make RDP connections from an OSX machine.

Edit:

Link to cord: http://cord.sourceforge.net/

Comment: coRD does **not** support TS/RD Gateway functionality.

Answer (score -2):

Microsoft Remote Desktop from the iTunes store

Comment: The question clearly states that they are not looking to RDP *from* their Mac.